# How to eliminate small contour areas using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I have tried to create a contour map in python with a fault using `KNearestNeighbors` as the interpolation method. However, the graph came back as with multiple small contour areas, which I want to eliminate:

[image: contour map generated]

I tried to use OpenCV to find all enclosed contour lines and set a boundary value as the maximum area, then eliminate all areas smaller than the boundary value.

However, I seemed to fail using the `findContours` method, as it only found contours around the fault. All other contours failed to present. The resulting graph and my code are as follows:

[image]

```
img = cv2.imread('contor_line.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  
ret, binary = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)  
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)  
cv2.drawContours(gray,contours,-1,(0,0,255),1)  
cv2.imshow("gray", gray)  
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is my first time using OpenCV, so thank you for helping.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using canny before you find contours, or threshold your image, which will make finding contours easier and better.